# How do I save a HashMap data in any location in my pc?

Tags: java, hashmap, save

Actually I have written a code which takes input of name and phone number, and returns a statement saying

`return "You are calling "+name+"; Phone Number: "+phoneNumber;`

Now it has a HashMap

key-name;
value- phone number...

It also has a method which takes input and stores it in the HashMap

And a method which returns the above statement to show that you are calling......

What i want to do is save the data in any location of the computer so that whenever a user enters name and phone number it is saved so that user can call anytime without saving the same stuff twice........

Comment: have you thought about a database...

Comment: So do you need to save your data into file - if yes, in which format (JSON, XML, raw text, serialize as Java object)?  Or do you want to persist your data into database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might just want to save the HashMap into the same file as the working directory of the program, then call up the contents of the file when initializing the HashMap for read and write purposes.

This can be done by perhaps storing each key and its value on a separate line of a text file using a BufferedWriter.

Ex.

```
BufferedWriter a = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myFile.txt"));
Set<String> keys = hashMap.keySet();
for(String key: keys) {
  a.write(key+" "+hashMap.get(key));
  write.newLine();
}
a.close();
```

This will store each key-value pair in the text file, with each entry on a separate line.
Then, when you run the program again, you want to loop through each line of the text file and initialize the new HashMap to contain all of those key-value pairs that you had saved.
Then, you will be able to add to that list and retrieve values. Whenever you are done with the user, make sure to re-update the text file with any new key-value mappings.

This updating at the start of the program can be done with the following:

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("myFile.txt"));
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
  String[] entry = scan.nextLine().split(" ");
  hashMap.put(entry[0], entry[1]);
}
```

Comment: How do I save the values

Comment: The first code snippet will save the values to a text file named "myFile.txt" in the project's directory. the a.close() command officially ends write operations to the file and saves it.